# Compare two dataframes and find the rows that are not in the second dataframe by comparing by one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I wish to take 2 dataframes with the same columns and compare them based of 1 column and produce a new dataframe of rows that do not appear in the second dataframe. Here is a snippet of the dataframes with the types printed as well. I have also tried `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` on them to ensure I am comparing apples to apples.

df1

```
Date       object
Open      float64
High      float64
Low       float64
Close     float64
Volume      int32
dtype: object
            Date    Open    High     Low   Close   Volume
0     2000-01-04   24.35   24.35   23.55   23.70  1372800
1     2000-01-05   23.80   23.90   23.38   23.38  2746800
2     2000-01-06   23.48   23.82   23.38   23.70  2243200
3     2000-01-07   23.60   23.60   23.12   23.45  1610400
4     2000-01-10   23.48   23.48   22.90   22.90  1728600
```

df2

```
Date      object
Open      object
High      object
Low       object
Close     object
Volume     int64
dtype: object
            Date    Open    High     Low   Close   Volume
0     2000-01-04   24.35   24.35   23.55   23.70  1372800
1     2000-01-05   23.80   23.90   23.38   23.38  2746800
2     2000-01-06   23.48   23.83   23.38   23.70  2243200
3     2000-01-07   23.60   23.60   23.13   23.45  1610400
```

OUTPUT

```
            Date    Open    High     Low   Close   Volume
4     2000-01-10   23.48   23.48   22.90   22.90  1728600
```

The code I use is:

```
df1[~df1.Date.isin(df2.Date.values)]
```

This works when I load df1 from a .csv  however when I pull it from a website it produces all lines.  I do not understand how the comparison is not seeing the dates as the same.

I have saved them both as .csv and compared them and I cannot see a difference.

Any help in diagnosing this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does your DF look like when pulled from website?

Comment: Are you converting the `Date` column into a `Datetime` object when doing it from the website?

Comment: Alizera: The 2 dataframes are a snippet of print(df) of both

Comment: Celius: Yes I have tried pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) on both dataframes before the comparison

Comment: looks like the problem is somewhere else and not your pandas code

Comment: You are correct. I have been at this for hours, I restarted my computer and works fine. Must have been something with VS...This question can be deleted if needed. Thanks and sorry for your time

Comment: `df1[~df1.Date.isin(df2.Date.values)]` Why use `.values` here? Also, I would recommend using `[ ]` for column access, instead of `.`/attribute style.